# Cakephp ctp files Not reads as php files

Tags: php, cakephp

I'am using Apache on centos 6.0 Logged as **Root** .
I was facing the issue `Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php` File permissions as the first issue after uploading Cakephp files . Then i managed to fix it by changing Tmp folder permissions to be Writable . 
now i'am facing new issue the php code doesnt seems to be reads :

The Page Display :

```
 Html->css('plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>
 Html->css('font-awesome'); ?>
 Html->css('sky-forms'); ?>
 Html->css('weather-icons.min.css'); ?> 
 Html->css('line-icons'); ?>
 Html->css('plugins/owl-carousel/owl.pack.css'); ?> 
 Html->css('plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css'); ?> 
 Html->css('animate'); ?> 
 Html->css('flexslider'); ?> 
 Html->css('revolution-slider.css'); ?> 
 Html->css('layerslider'); ?> 
 Html->css('essentials'); ?>
 Html->css('layout'); ?> 
 Html->css('header-default'); ?>
 Html->css('footer-default'); ?>
 Html->css('color_scheme/red.css'); ?>
 Html->script('plugins/modernizr.min.js'); ?>
```

I 'am Really confused on how can i fix it , i was trying to search for a solutions but i found nothing .

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I tried To use The `PHP SHORT TAG` So i tried to set it to `on` on php.ini and restart my apache server but it doesnt seems to be working i tried to change some configuration on my PHP.ini located in /etc/php.ini and it doesnt seems to be working too that was too strange  but after using `phpinfo()` it was the right configuration on the same path /etc/php.ini **BUT** there were other Parsed .ini files so i deleted the php.ini located in /etc/php.ini and everything seems to be working ! on Centos 6.0